# How do I invalidate HTTP cache with the Location header?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, http, httpwebrequest, http-caching

On [cache invalidation](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.10), the HTTP spec says:

> Some HTTP methods MUST cause a cache to invalidate an entity. This is either the entity referred to by the Request-URI, or by the Location or Content-Location headers (if present).

I am trying to invalidate an entry in my cache through the use of the **Location** header, but it doesn't appear to be working.  Here's my use case:

1. `15:13:23.9988 | GET | folders/folder.34/contents - 200 (OK)`
2. `15:13:24.1318 | PUT | folders/folder.34/contents/test.docx - 201 (Created)`
3. `15:13:24.1548 | GET | folders/folder.34/contents - 200 (OK) (cached)`

The response of (2) contains a **Location** header with the URI used in requests (1) and (3).  I believe this should invalidate the cached entry for *folders/folder.34/contents*, but the response in (3) appears to be coming from cache anyway according to the [HttpWebResponse.IsFromCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.isfromcache.aspx) property.

I have tried numerous URI formats in the **Location** header, including:

- `Location: ../../../folders/folder.34/contents`  (and other assorted '../' counts)
- `Location: folders/folder.34/contents`
- `Location: /folders/folder.34/contents`
- `Location: http://myhostname/folders/folder.34/contents`

But still (3) always seems to come from cache.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTPBis is much clearer:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p6-cache-22#section-6

```
Because unsafe request methods (Section 4.2.1 of [Part2]) such as
PUT, POST or DELETE have the potential for changing state on the
origin server, intervening caches can use them to keep their contents
up-to-date.

A cache MUST invalidate the effective Request URI (Section 5.5 of
[Part1]) as well as the URI(s) in the Location and Content-Location
response header fields (if present) when a non-error response to a
request with an unsafe method is received.
```

So if this is not the behavior you're seeing, my assumption would simply be that the particular HTTP client you are using does *not* have the correct behavior.

I'd especially expect:

```
Location: /folders/folder.34/contents
```

To have the correct behavior.

Comment: Is it plausible that the WinInet cache (eg. IE, .NET) would not exhibit the correct behavior?

Comment: @ladenedge: of course ;) HTTP is quite extensive, and any client out there will have some bugs. Besides, I reckon you've just proven this yourself too. Question is: did you make the mistake to think your software stack is infallible, ignoring your own logic? ;)

Comment: it seems so fundamental, though (sob).  Anyway, thank you for the help!

Comment: I work almost all day on HTTP and reading/implementing rfcs. I'm pretty sure I never knew this was a requirement. Super useful though! I wonder how well other clients do this.